# Many to many - proper usage

Tags: django

I have models like this:

```
User:
    #somefields
    apps = models.ManyToManyField(App)
```

Here, User is created initially during registration. He links apps using many to many in a separate page where user selects(multiple) only apps, no other fields.

What is the best way to populate apps in Django ?

For example, if we can create User also, we can simply use modelform where .save(commit=False) will create user and .save_m2m() will link apps. But here we dont need to create User. We will be having user already, we only need to add apps. How ?

**Newly added details**:
I know how to do with normal "form" and normal web way. But I want to write quality code so want to know. If there is nothing wrong in using normal form then its fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, but for example:

```
class UserAppForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['apps']
```

And in your view, you configure the routing so that you can:

- Get the ID of the user to select
- Raise an error if you do not find the ID (Instead of creating a new one)
- Initialize the form with the user

For example:

```
def user_add_app(request, pk):
  user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)

  if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserAppForm(request.POST, instance=user)

    if form.is_valid():
      user = form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(<some redirect>)

  else:
    form = EmployeeForm(instance=user)

  return render(request, "<some html file>", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not fully understand the question (Please clarify if it's not the case), but there is no problem having two forms on the same model:

- One form to create the User, without selecting apps (Which will be empty)
- One form to add Apps to the User, taking into account that it already exists (And is not created at this time).

Does it answer the question ?

Comment: First of all, please ignore how to create user as that is not issue. One form to add apps to user? But How ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ModelForm` form with `model = App` and a `User` field. Now when creating the form set an initial value for `User` :

```
form = AppForm(initial={'user': 1})
```